# cant count works ad character with pdfbox in java

Tags: java, pdfbox

```
class ReadPDF {


    public void Read() throws IOException {

        int amountOfWords = 0;
        int amountOfChars = 0;
        String sourceCode ="";

        try {
            PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\Users\\ccw\\Desktop\\articles\\RECYCLING-BEHAVIOUR-AMONG-MALAYSIAN-TERTIARY-STUDENTS.pdf"));
            String text = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);

            sourceCode = sourceCode.replace ("-", "").replace (".", "");

            while(doc!=null){
                String[] words = sourceCode.split(" ");
                amountOfWords = amountOfWords + words.length;
                for (String word : words) {
                    amountOfChars = amountOfChars + word.length();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Amount of Chars is " + amountOfChars);
            System.out.println("Amount of Words is " + (amountOfWords + 1));
            System.out.println("Average Word Length is "+ (amountOfChars/amountOfWords));


        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

I'm trying to count all the words and character in a pdf file by using pdfbox.
But now i getting an error, sourceCode is not initialize

Comment: Change `String sourceCode` to `String sourceCode="";`

Comment: The variable `sourceCode` has to be set to something before you can use `sourceCode.replace()` otherwise it will remain null.  Please edit your answer to include the code in text format instead of a picture.  Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanVanDam post edited

Comment: @Choy do you still have a issue after changing ?

Comment: @manfromnowhere idk, i changed my code and run but the program just keep running without showing any output

Comment: btw is it correct ?in this line: while(doc!=null)

Comment: replace `string text ` with `sourcecode`

Comment: @preciousbetine the program just keep running without showing any output

Comment: Replace this line `sourceCode = sourceCode.replace ("-", "").replace (".", "");` with `sourceCode = text.replace ("-", "").replace (".", "");`

Comment: @preciousbetine same, no output

Comment: remove the while loop

Comment: @preciousbetine yaya finally it works

Comment: @preciousbetine any idea how to do if i want to count how many a,b or c in the pdf file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184123/discussion-between-choy-and-preciousbetine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line `sourceCode = sourceCode.replace ("-", "").replace (".", "");` with `sourceCode = text.replace ("-", "").replace (".", "");` .and remove the while loop